# Returning the highest and lowest numbers in a string: Ruby

Tags: ruby

Not sure what I'm doing incorrect but I seem to be getting it woefully wrong.

The question is, you are given a string of space separated numbers, and have to return the highest and lowest number.

Note:
All numbers are valid Int32, no need to validate them.
There will always be at least one number in the input string.
Output string must be two numbers separated by a single space, and highest number is first.

```
def high_and_low(numbers)
  # numbers contains a string of space seperated numbers 
  #return the highest and lowest number 
 numbers.minmax { |a, b| a.length <=> b.length }  
   

end
```

Output:

```
`high_and_low': undefined method `minmax' for "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6":String
```

Answer (score 12):

`minmax` is not implemented for a string. You need to split your string into an array first. But note that `split` will return an array of strings, not numbers, you will need to translate the strings to integers (`to_i`) in the next step.

Because `minmax` returns the values in the opposite order than required, you need to rotate the array with `reverse` and then just `join` those numbers with whitespace for the final result.

```
numbers = "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"

def high_and_low(numbers)
  numbers.split.minmax_by(&:to_i).reverse.join(' ')
end

high_and_low(numbers)
#=> "542 -214"
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the detailed breakdown!

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
numbers_array = numbers.split(' ')
"#{numbers_array.max} #{numbers_array.min}"
```

If you're starting with a string of numbers you may have to cast the `.to_i` after the call to split.

In that case:

```
numbers_array = numbers.split(' ').map { |n| n.to_i }
"#{numbers_array.max} #{numbers_array.min}"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're starting with a String, you must turn it into an Array to cast `minmax` on it.
Also, make sure to compare Integers by casting `.map(&:to_i)` on the Array; otherwise you'd compare the code-point instead of the numerical value.

```rb
def get_maxmin(string)
  string.split(' ')
        .map(&:to_i)
        .minmax
        .reverse
        .join(' ')
end
```

Comment: Indeed, I'm comparing Strings instead of Integers, see my edit

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to convert the string to an array.

```
def high_and_low(str)
  str.gsub(/-?\d+/).
      reduce([-Float::INFINITY, Float::INFINITY]) do |(mx,mn),s|
        n = s.to_i
        [[mx,n].max, [mn,n].min]
      end
 end
```

```
 high_and_low "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
   #=> [542, -214]
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/@CarySwoveland/VagueTemporalScientists)

This uses the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that has one argument and no block, so it returns an enumerator that I've chained to [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (a.k.a. `inject`). `gsub` therefore merely generates matches of the regular expression `/-?\d+/` and performs no substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this kata

```
def high_and_low(numbers)
  numbers.split.map(&:to_i).minmax.reverse.join(' ')
end

Test.assert_equals(high_and_low("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"), "542 -214")

#Test Passed: Value == "542 -214"
```

Some docs about methods:
[String#split](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split) [Array#map](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map) [Array#minmax](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/minmax) [Array#reverse](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/reverse) [Array#join](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/join)

More about [Symbol#to_proc](https://apidock.com/rails/Symbol/to_proc)

`numbers.split.map(&:to_i)` is same as `number.split.map { |p| p.to_i }`

> But "minmax_by(&:to_i)" looks better, for sure I guess.